# How do I escape and replace text with quotes in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, escaping

I have a Rails 4.1 app which uses Postgresql. I want to replace all of the following text in my database:

```
'100': 'hello world
```

with this:

```
'100': 'greetings!\\n hello world
```

Here's one of my attempts to escape and replace the text:

```
query = "update notes set text = replace(text, \"'100': 'hello world\", \"'100': 'greetings!\\n hello world'\" )"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
```

I tried a few more ways but they didn't work. How can I correctly escape and replace the text?

Comment: That looks like `json`. If so, don't just do a text replace on it; you should really parse the json, extract the value for the key, and replace the value. (If you're on PostgreSQL 9.3 you may be able to do this in-database without use of extra language functions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this in ruby instead of SQL. Here's the function I created:

```
def replace_text(id)
  note = Note.find(id)
  note.text = note.text.gsub(/'100'\s{0,1}:\s{0,1}'hello world/, "'100': 'greetings!\\nhello world")
  note.save
end
```